androidx.test.espresso.screenshot.captureToBitmap with 3.6.x
Starting with Android Espresso libs 3.6.0 the captureToBitmap was changed
Previous with 3.5.x:
fun ViewInteraction.captureToBitmap(): Bitmap {

using it
onView(isRoot()).captureToBitmap().writeToTestStorage("${javaClass.simpleName}_${nameRule.methodName}-open")

Now in 3.6.x
I only found
class CaptureToBitmapAction(val bitmapReceiver: ViewActions.BitmapReceiver) : ViewAction {

So I tried
class BitmapReceiver(name: String) : ViewActions.BitmapReceiver {
    override fun onBitmapCaptured(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

val receiver = BitmapReceiver("${javaClass.simpleName}_${nameRule.methodName}-open")
onView(isRoot()).perform(CaptureToBitmapAction(receiver))

But I don't know what to do in onBitmapCaptured
The question is now, how to do an Espresso test screenshot with 3.6.x ?

I made it work. Instead of
onView(ViewMatchers.isRoot())
    .captureToBitmap()
    .writeToTestStorage("${javaClass.simpleName_${nameRule.methodName}")

I use now
onView(ViewMatchers.isRoot())
    .perform(captureToBitmap { bitmap: Bitmap -> bitmap.writeToTestStorage("${javaClass.simpleName}_${nameRule.methodName}") })

